# Value Of for loop item is not changing

Tags: ios, for-loop, swift4.2

Below is my view controller. I want to change background color of view depends on coming binary data. But my for loop `sendingBit` variable is showing always 0 value. Value of `sendingBit` is not changing.

```
            class ViewController: UIViewController {

            @IBOutlet weak var backgroundView: UIView!

            var timer = Timer()
            var condition = "black"
            var count = 0

 var bitEmementsArray = [0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]            var currentColor = "black"

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.99, target: self, selector: #selector(animation), userInfo: nil, repeats : true)

            }

            @objc func animation()
            {
    for sendingBit in bitEmementsArray {
                print(sendingBit)
                if currentColor == "black" && sendingBit == 0 {
                    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                    currentColor = "grey"
                    break;
                }
                else if currentColor == "black" && sendingBit == 1 {
                    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                    currentColor = "white"
                    break;
                }
                else if currentColor == "grey" && sendingBit == 0 {
                    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                    currentColor = "black"
                    break;
                }
                else if currentColor == "grey" && sendingBit == 1 {
                    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                    currentColor = "white"
                    break;
                }
                else if currentColor == "white" && sendingBit == 0 {
                    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                    currentColor = "black"
                    break;
                }
                else if currentColor == "white" && sendingBit == 1 {
                    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                    currentColor = "grey"
                    break;
                }

            }
                count += 1
                print(count)

                if count == bitEmementsArray.count + 1
                {
                    count = 0
                    timer.invalidate()
                    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
                    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                }
            }
 }
```

Comment: what is hexaToBinary ? Show full code of func hexaToBinary

Answer (score 0):

the issue is not related to the scheduled timer I'd say. The `Timer.scheduledTimer` method makes sure that your code is running on your main thread (UIThread). Stripping down your code to just the basics of starting the timer and setting the background shows that this is properly working.

Try to remove the timer and see where the code fails. It is probably somewhere in your color generation code. Maybe you can start a new thread related to that as soon as you've found out where the issue is at exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I like this syntax better than what you've got. Seems to work for me in a playground.

```
import UIKit

var backgroundView = UIView()
backgroundView.backgroundColor = .black

var bitEmementsArray = [0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]

for sendingBit in bitEmementsArray {
   switch (sendingBit, backgroundView.backgroundColor) {
   case (0, UIColor.black):
      backgroundView.backgroundColor = .gray
   case (1, UIColor.gray):
      backgroundView.backgroundColor = .black
   default:
      print("default")
   }
}
```

Might as well use the prettier pattern matching syntax sugar.
Also, stringly typing a UIColor isn't a good idea in practice when you can just access the variable directly.

Comment: bitEmementsArray is definitely an array of integers if you're allowing the compiler to infer the type itself.

Comment: Which this does. So long as you are actually iterating over an array of integers. If you think anything other than that is happening then that is your problem. bitEmementsArray is not Data or a byte stream; it's an [Int] according to the compiler.

Comment: You need to break and verify the state of bitEmementsArray at the beginning of the loop. Likely that array does not contain what you think it does. Maybe it was mutated at runtime. There's no reason a for-in loop is going to make up the value of the elements during iteration.

Comment: It's also important to note that this code won't work properly to "animate" any color changes. That fast iterator is going to run much more quickly than you will be able to observe a view's background color update. That will only happen once a draw cycle.